# Calculate average each group items

Tags: java

I have 168 items in my database, How can I do a for loop and calculate the average each 24 of 168 items. What I did was I could only calculate the first average of 24 items, how can I move it to the next 24 until it reaches 168 and stops?

```
 @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        if (result.getCount() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> mStoreData= new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0; i < 168; i++) {
                result.moveToPosition(i);
                String indexes = result.getString(DBContract.COLUMN_IDX_AQI);
                buffer.add(indexes);
                    if( buffer.size() == 24 ) {
                        for (String value : buffer) {
                            value += value;
                            array = Integer.parseInt(value) / 24;
                        }
                    }
                    mStoreData.add(array);
                    Log.d("Data", "Array" + mStoreData);
            }
        }
        task=null;
    }
```

Comment: empty `buffer` in the `if` ???

Comment: What you mean is  buffer.clear(); ?

Comment: If you're open to using a 3rd party library like `rx-java` that can be useful. If this is something very specific in your program you can do it manually. If you're constantly using streams and need more complex logic (like buffering) that java currently doen't offer - consider an alternative.

Comment: You don't need to calculate array every time you increment value; Calculate it after you finish the loop.